# what mistake have i done here in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, sublimetext3

I have tried changing the module varialbe

```
<ul>
    <li ng-controller="ulCtrl"><a ng- href="" class ="active" >{{customers}}</a></li>
    <li><a ng-href="#JOBS">JOBS</a></li>
    <li><a ng-href="#ESTIMATES" >ESTIMATES</a></li>
    <li><a ng-href="#INVOICE" >INVOICE</a></li>
    <li class="right"><a ng-href="#ABOUT">ABOUT</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Controller**

```
var demoapp = angular.module("myApp", []);

demoapp.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.image = "media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_200_200/…" }); 

demoapp.controller("ulCtrl", function($scope) { 
    $scope.customers = "CUSTOMERSSS" });
```

After running the code I get this : `{{customers}}`

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: You are getting what?

Comment: the value CUSTOMERSS is not printing on the console,

Comment: Can we see the code for controller?

Comment: it's printing {{customers}} the variable itself

Comment: <script >
 var demoapp = angular.module("myApp",[]);
  demoapp.controller(
   "MyCtrl",function($scope){
    $scope.image = "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_200_200/AAEAAQAAAAAAAAkTAAAAJDczYmIyYmU3LWExYTAtNGMwZS04Y2RhLTUzN2VjYTU3ZmI3ZQ.png"
   });
  demoapp.controller("ulCtrl",function($scope){
   $scope.customers = "CUSTOMERSSS"

  });
 </script>

Comment: Yes because your bindings are not working perfectly

Comment: where have i gone wrong?

Comment: @manjunath: I have edited your question adding the controller code, please accept the changes, also have posted the answer!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You might have posted partial code, according to your comments your controller should be like below.

**DEMO**

```js
var demoapp = angular.module("myApp",[]); 
demoapp.controller("ulCtrl",function($scope){ 
$scope.customers = "CUSTOMERSSS" ;
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>  
  </head>
  <body>
  <div ng-controller="ulCtrl" style='padding: 40px;'> 
  <li ng-controller="ulCtrl"><a ng- href="" class ="active" >{{customers}}</a></li>
    <li><a ng-href="#JOBS">JOBS</a></li>
    <li><a ng-href="#ESTIMATES" >ESTIMATES</a></li>
    <li><a ng-href="#INVOICE" >INVOICE</a></li>
    <li class="right"><a ng-href="#ABOUT">ABOUT</a></li>
</ul>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's still has the same problem

Comment: you are not telling the problem

Comment: <script >
 var demoapp = angular.module("myApp",[]);
  demoapp.controller(
   "MyCtrl",function($scope){
    $scope.image = "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_200_200/AAEAAQAAAAAAAAkTAAAAJDczYmIyYmU3LWExYTAtNGMwZS04Y2RhLTUzN2VjYTU3ZmI3ZQ.png";
   });
  demoapp.controller("ulCtrl",function($scope){
   $scope.customers = "CUSTOMERSSS";

  });
 </script>

Comment: <ul  class="bottomnav" >
 
 <li ng-controller="ulCtrl" ><a ng-href="" class ="active" >{{customers}}</a></li>
 <li><a ng-href="#JOBS">JOBS</a></li>
 <li><a ng-href="#ESTIMATES" >ESTIMATES</a></li>
 <li><a ng-href="#INVOICE" >INVOICE</a></li>
 <li class="right"><a ng-href="#ABOUT">ABOUT</a></li>
 
 </ul>

Comment: @manjunath man tell what is the issue. dont post the repeated code

Comment: @manjunath are you blind? cant you see CUSTOMERSS getting printed?

Comment: it must print CUSTOMERSSS but it's printing {{customers}}

Answer (score -2):

Here is your answer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="container" style="padding-top:30px">
  <ul>
      <li ng-controller="ulCtrl"><a ng-href="" class="active">{{customers}}</a></li>
      <li><a ng-href="#JOBS">JOBS</a></li>
      <li><a ng-href="#ESTIMATES">ESTIMATES</a></li>
      <li><a ng-href="#INVOICE">INVOICE</a></li>
      <li class="right"><a ng-href="#ABOUT">ABOUT</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.image = "media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_200_200/…"
});

app.controller("ulCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.customers = "CUSTOMERSSS"
});
```

working [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cm9dxRdXe3ANj59sUef5?p=preview)

**Update 1**

Updated code with `demoApp`, check http://plnkr.co/edit/ecYw2lPdLmdOjt9qgWxJ?p=preview

Comment: Well whosoever is marking downvote have the guts to comment why?

Comment: <ul  class="bottomnav" >
 
 <li ng-controller="ulCtrl" ><a ng-href="" class ="active" >{{customers}}</a></li>
 <li><a ng-href="#JOBS">JOBS</a></li>
 <li><a ng-href="#ESTIMATES" >ESTIMATES</a></li>
 <li><a ng-href="#INVOICE" >INVOICE</a></li>
 <li class="right"><a ng-href="#ABOUT">ABOUT</a></li>
 
 </ul>

Comment: What's this? Also can you tell me what error you are getting in console?

Comment: <script >
 var demoapp = angular.module("myApp",[]);
  demoapp.controller(
   "MyCtrl",function($scope){
    $scope.image = "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_200_200/AAEAAQAAAAAAAAkTAAAAJDczYmIyYmU3LWExYTAtNGMwZS04Y2RhLTUzN2VjYTU3ZmI3ZQ.png";
   });
  demoapp.controller("ulCtrl",function($scope){
   $scope.customers = "CUSTOMERSSS";

  });
 </script>

Comment: there's no error , it must print CUSTOMERSSS but it's printing {{customers}}

Comment: Dear! Have you checked my demo? It is printing CUSTOMERSSS only, just click on the link and check

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Ip_kSaz3214kEohra6uezxWGLVdUk2onB1UxbBHhl3g/edit?usp=sharing